# Pulling a value from a database, and changing the value before printing

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Ok, so I am almost done programming a module for an ecommerce store I run. I am pulling a value from the database :

```
shipChange = rs("ordShipType")

response.write rs("ordID") & vbTab & rs("ordTrackNum") & vbTab &  shipChange & vbTab & OrderDate & vbCrlf
```

I need to detect if the value of shipChange is = UPS Ground, if it is I need it to be changed to UPS before printing, if the value is USPS First Class, I need it to be changed into just USPS. The results are spit into a tab delimited text file and there will be multiple values pulled, so it needs to keep checking until all values have been read and changed.

Comment: So do so. `shipChange = rs("OrdShipType") if shipChange = "UPS Ground" then shipChange = "UPS"`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select Case` to determine what to change how and `Split` to get the first 'word' of your UPS*.

```
Option Explicit

Dim shipChange
For Each shipChange In Array("UPS Ground", "USPS First Class", "Reitender Bote")
   WScript.Stdout.Write shipChange
   Select Case shipChange
     Case "UPS Ground", "USPS First Class"
       shipChange = Split(shipChange)(0)
     Case "Reitender Bote"
       shipChange = "Horse"
     Case Else
       shipChange = "????"
   End Select
   WScript.Echo " =>", shipChange
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 21100431.vbs
UPS Ground => UPS
USPS First Class => USPS
Reitender Bote => Horse
```

Comment: Nice. I think the OP wants to also know how to read in text from a file via ASP. At this stage, I'm guessing classic ASP.

Comment: I was able to figure it all out, I did use the case method. Worked great. Thanks! I't still spits the changed values out to the text file as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
shipChange = Replace(rs("ordShipType"), "USPS First Class", "USPS")
shipChange = Replace(shipChange, "UPS Ground", "UPS")
```